# Laravel decrypt hashed security answer for customer to see on front-end API

Tags: php, laravel, hash

I'm building a feature in my Laravel 8 API to allow customers to set a Security Question & Security Answer. A customer can set their question via a HTML `<select>` and set their answer via a standard HTML5 input.

When their answer is saved, I'm hashing it, for security purposes in case data is exposed, however, in my API, I need to somehow decrypt the hashed value for the logged in user so that they can see their answer, and make amendments to it, or change it.

Right now I'm saving the data via a method:

```php
/**
 * Update user's security questions
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function updateSecurityQuestions(Request $request)
{

    // get request data
    $request_data = $request->only(['security_question', 'security_answer']);

    // validation
    $validator = Validator::make($request_data, [
        'security_question' => 'nullable|in:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8',
        'security_answer' => 'nullable|max:128'
    ]);

    // if validation fails
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->error_response['errors'] = $validator->messages();
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'It looks like you missed something', $this->error_response], 400);
    }

    // attempt to save the user
    try {

        $question = (isset($request_data['security_question']) && !empty($request_data['security_question'])) ? htmlspecialchars($request_data['security_question']) : null;
        $answer = (isset($request_data['security_answer']) && !empty($request_data['security_answer'])) ? htmlspecialchars($request_data['security_answer']) : null;

        $id = Auth::user();
        $user = User::findOrFail($id['id']);
        $user->security_question = !$answer ? null : $question;
        $user->security_answer = !$question ? null : Hash::make($answer);

        $user->save();

        if ($user->security_question == null && $user->security_answer == null) {
          return response()->json(['success' => true, 'type' => 'warning', 'message' => 'Your security question settings are incomplete'], 200);
        }

        // everything went okay!
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Your security question and answer has been updated'], 200);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        // catch the error
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'We was unable to update your security question and answer, please try again later'], 422);

    }

}
```

You can see I'm hashing it, but this value is returned to the front-end via an API in JSON amongst other user data:

```
{
  "security_answer": "$2y$10$gGa6OC34UBzQzMNtVoo.EOj8W9WD5THY68bQME0y6AnRJjYFWWcqO"
}
```

This is no good because the user sees that value in the input, which obviously isn't good.

Could I not just do something like?

```php
if (Hash::check($user->security_answer, $user->security_answer)) {
    // return the answer?
}
```

What do I do here?

Comment: Hashes are _one-way_, you cannot turn the hamburger back into a cow. If you don't want the user to see the field, then either add server-side logic to not send it, or client-side logic to not display it.

Comment: So how does a user find out what they previously set? Or do security answers tend not to do this and simply provide an "override"

Comment: In your case, they don't. It's basically a second password. Skipping arguments about "security/recovery questions" in general, keeping it hashed like this is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why you execute save before the if? You need to make it after check if everything's okay

```
$user->save();
```